# What are the roots of "dungeons" as a theme for "dungeons and dragons"

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming, dungeon

As far as I know, the roots of role playing games and dungeons and dragons lie in wargaming and conflict simulations?

Is there a reason known (perhaps from an interview) why dungeons were a successful playing ground for the genre now known as "roleplaying" and the topos of "dungeon crawl"?

Why were it dungeons?

Is it the *limitation* of the field?

Comment: The question is different, but the answer is what I was looking for. Thanks.